# Seemingly compressed file with some readable text

Tags: decryption, decompress

I've been trying to modify a data file within an app which has random lines of readable text but is mostly incomprehensible, it has no file extension.

I think its compressed because I was able to find an older version of the same data file [same name, same location in game files] which has a much larger file size and is in plain text.

By default in the game files, the encrypted/compressed version is used but if I replace it with the older version it still works[all changes between them are however not present], this makes me think that the game does some sort of check to see if the file is compressed then decompresses it if appropriate.

What can potentially be done to decompress the current data file, or if its not compressed to convert it to plain text.

Thanks.

Edit 1:
Here are links to the original data files:

[compressed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ThunlNtdfwK_hiFpG6ioTkrTpd62E5KR/view?usp=sharing)

[uncompressed older version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mVU-gtYXglSCs6kX-fYWa5yu-neO-Nlo/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks Gordon Freeman.

Comment: The "data" file is corrupted, it was at least opened and saved with a text editor.
With a hexadecimal editor we see in the header of the file that the bytes which should be 0x00 are replaced by 0x20 etc ...  
You should share the original "data" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can use AssetsBundleExtractor (Windows)
https://github.com/DerPopo/UABE/releases
to open and decompress the file data_a.